# How do I check on the status of an unsafe insert into mongo using python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

If I save a document on mongo with

```
val = db[table].save(doc, w=0)
```

How do I check on the status of the async call using val ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val returns the ObjectId.  You can then later query for that document to make sure it was written.